# Why am I receiving a .class is expected? Trying to call a method in java

Tags: java, class, methods, expected-exception

I'm pretty new to programming feel free to be harsh in your replies. Anything helps.
Basically I'm trying to call in a method LineCount() but when I try to compile the command prompt complains about .class being expected at String[A] (line 8 I believe)

*Thank you guys for all your help! My code works now! I really appreciate all the input

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class FileCount{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        String[] in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        System.out.println(lineCount(String[] in);

    }

    public static void lineCount(String[] A){

        // check number of command line arguments
        if(args.length != 1){
            System.err.println("Usage: LineCount file");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // count lines, words, and chars in file
        int lineCount = 0;
        while( in.hasNextLine() ){
            in.nextLine();
            lineCount++;
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println( args[0]+" contains "+lineCount+" lines" );

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to redeclare the type of `in` when you pass it as an argument in your `lineCount` invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**->** There are many mistakes in your code, Besides other answers want to add that, Since you are passing `lineCount(in)` as an argument  to the `linecount()` method , then refer to the parameter in `lineCount(String[] A)` now via `A` variable and not `in`.

**->** Also you cannot refer to `args` inside `linecount()` method since it is a parameter of `main()` method and hence is limited to it in its scope.

**->** You cannot do this `String[] in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));` , you are assigning a `Scanner` instance to an String Array, you have to do it like this

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
```

**->** You are calling `linecount()` inside a `System.out.println()` method , although your method `linecount()` has a return type of void, Dont put your method inside `print()` function , because anyways it has got `print()` statements inside it.

**->** Maybe last , there could be more , Since your `in` variable is of type `Scanner` , change your method declaration to

```
 public static void lineCount(Scanner in){
```

and now call it like `lineCount(in)` from `main()`.

Edit :- Since you are a beginner i will give you working code for your question:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class FileCount{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


      // check number of command line arguments, and check it in main()
       if(args.length != 1){
            System.err.println("Usage: LineCount file");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    System.out.println( args[0]+" contains "+lineCount(in)+" lines" ); //call this line in main() and not in linecount() as you refer to both args and need the linecount.

    }

    public static int lineCount(Scanner in){


        // count lines, words, and chars in file
        int lineCount = 0;
        while( in.hasNextLine() ){
            in.nextLine();
            lineCount++;
        }
        in.close();

        return lineCount; //return the linecount from method 

    }

}
```

Comment: This answer covers most mistakes, code has a lot of mistakes in it.

Answer (score 4):

First of all

```
  System.out.println(lineCount(String[] in); // this is incomplete need to close)
```

Assuming you did mistake while you putting the question here, Change

```
 System.out.println(lineCount(String[] in));
```

To

```
  System.out.println(lineCount(in));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem `String[] in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));` creating a Scanner object and asigning it to an array it does not work like this. Change your code to read the file and store it in some arraylist like

```
    List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        // find next line
        String line = in.nextLine();
        list.add(line);
    }
```

Then if you want can convert to list to String array which is not really necessary like this

```
    String[] strArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);

            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(strArr));
    lineCount(strArr);
```

Then call the lineCount() method which counts the lines in the files.

```
public static void lineCount(String[] A){
    System.out.println("File contains "+A.length+" lines" );

}
```